# Is P closed under subwords?

Tags: complexity-theory, closure-properties, polynomial-time

Given a language $L\subseteq \Sigma^*$ in $P$, is the language

$subwords(L) = \{v\in\Sigma^* : \text{there exist } u,w\in \Sigma^* \text{ with } uvw\in L\}$

that consists of all subwords of words in $L$ also guaranteed to lie in $P$?

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: This is a dump of an exercise problem, not a question. If you have a specific question regarding the wording of the problem or concrete steps in your own attempts at solving the problem, feel free to edit accordingly and we can reopen the question. See also [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/470/) for our homework policy, and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594) for a relevant discussion. You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/). If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $L$ be the language consisting of a description of a Turing machine (bounded by $\#$ on both sides) followed by a terminating computation (both description and computation are over $\{0,1\}$). What is the language $\mathit{subwords}(L) \cap \#\Sigma^*\#$?

Comment: Thanks for the example. So subwords(L) is generally not even decidable.